# jQuery 1.6.1 with jquery UI tabss causes onclick to fire?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I just upgraded to jQuery 1.6.1 and noticed that when I select a tab in jQuery UI it fires any onclick events that I may have in html. In previous versions of jQuery this did not happen. I was wondering if something has changed in jQuery for this to happen.

An example of this is here:

[Exampe of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/fUas6/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/fUas6/2/)

- Simply change the refence to jquery 1.5.2 and you will see the event doesn't fire

If I bind click event using jQuery $("foo").bind("click"..... then the event is not fired

So I'm guessing by design jQuery fires native onclick events?

Regards DotnetShadow

Comment: That is likely a bug. I would submit it as such.

Comment: Simple: merely remove your evil, wicked, obtrusive script bindings!  Problem solved!  No, but seriously, probably a bug like Daniel said. :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the browser, But inline code takes priority over header code...

It was more of a bug to prevent it firing in the previous version of jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is not jQuery :-) They are developed by separate teams and is likely that a new version of jQuery will not be 100% backwards compatible. I would try the [latest release](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/05/jquery-ui-1-8-13/) (and even the [development builds](http://jqueryui.com/development)) and, if it is still a problem, make the jQuery UI team aware of your issue by [raising a bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/).